# Reading and writing array from and to an file

Tags: perl

I wrote the following functions in Perl:

```
sub save
{
   my($dir,$name,%hash) = @_;

   my $prop = Config::Properties->new();
   my $file = $dir."/.".$name;

   open my $fh, ">", $file or return 0;

    foreach my $p (keys(%hash))
    {
       $properties->setProperty($p => $hash{$p});
    }

   $properties->store($fh);
   close ($fh);
   return 1;
}

sub read
{
    my ($dir,$name) = @_;

    my ($user, $start_time, $workdir, $rules_file);
    my $file = $dir."/.".$name;

    open my $fh, "<", $file or return 0;

    my $prop = Config::Properties->new();
    $properties->load($fh);
    my %hash = $properties->properties;

    close ($fh);
    return %hash;
}
```

In order to save the configuration hash to a file and then read it. But if one of the hash values is an array, it will display just the address of that array. What change should I do to my code in order to make it support arrays read and write?

Comment: See also [`setFromTree`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::Properties#METHODS). It seems it could be used to add array values

Comment: Does it need to be a properties file? Seems to me that it would be easier to just save the data structure as JSON or YAML.

Comment: @DaveCross Good suggestion, How can I do it with JSON?

Comment: @TTaJTa4: Use the [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) module's `encode` and `decode` methods.